# Drag objects with Box2D, Cocos2D and Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocos2d-android

I need to create a simple game in which one object moves on the screen based on touch (mouse) events. In other words I want to be able to drag it on an Android machine's screen.

Looking everywhere there are many great examples of "ball" type games in which a ball is bouncing on the screen, responding to gravity and even colliding with other objects, static or dynamic. But nothing that actually has an object that I can touch and move on the screen.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look at b2MouseJoint.

Comment: in cocos2d-android , ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent event)

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I'm going to test this with the code found in this link http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7219 starting with robodude666's answer.